# Safari blocks mouse click for links aligned with unrelated image

Tags: css, safari, positioning, margin

http://www.stringfieldassociates.com/

In Safari, all nav links that are horizontally aligned with the large central image are blocked and can't be clicked. It's like the image is taking up the width of the page, but it's not--it has a set width and height, and the only CSS applied to it is margin-top and a negative margin-right to position it. I had used positioning before but this bug cropped up in Firefox and IE. Using margins for positioning worked fine everywhere but Safari, apparently.

The image is inside the div that makes up the blue bar on the top. That bar is a div and it just has the menu as a list and then the image.

Any ideas? I almost never see Safari bugs that aren't also in Firefox, so I am stumped.

Jeremy

Comment: remove height from #cap and you will see what's going on, it is not a margin problem. Not just safary btw, it doesn't work on webkit browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with:

```
#header_img{
   left: 50%;
   margin-left:-230px;
   position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: This did the trick, thanks! I had come close to having this before, but only had the left percentage rule which didn't fix the position. I guess the margin-left does that in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an absolute position on that header image instead of a negative margin right.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, you and negative had the same idea on this one and it was correct.  :)